# Fourier transform taylor series expansion

Tags: probability, fourier-analysis

Given that

$$\varphi_X(\xi)=\hat{f}_X(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f_X(x)e^{i\xi x}$$

where $\xi = 2\pi v$, I perform TSE on $e^{i\xi x}$ (around $0$) obtaining that $$e^{i\xi x} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^j \xi^jx^j}{j!}$$

We then see that:

$$\varphi_X(\xi)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^j \xi^j}{j!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^jf_X(x)dx$$

We can see that the integral is moment of order $j$: $M(X^j)=\mathbb{E}[X^j]$

If I now perform the TSE on $\varphi_X(\xi)$ itself (also around zero):

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^j}{j!} \frac{d^j}{d\xi^j} \varphi_X(0)$$

Thus:

$$\frac{d^j}{d\xi^j}\varphi_X(0)=i^j M(X^j)$$

My question is rather trivial, given that $j=1$ in the above, what is the result. It appears that my lecture notes contain an error, but I would not challenge my lecturer.

I obtain: $\mathbb{E}[X]=i\frac{d}{d\xi}\varphi_X(0)$, whereas I have minus in front of the $i$ in the notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move the ${\rm i}$ from the right hand side of $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} \xi}\varphi_X(0)={\rm i} M(X^j)$ to the left-hand side, you get $\frac 1 {\rm i}$ which is $- {\rm i}$, so there is a minus sign, indeed.